# How can I make a UIWebView to always really bounce?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I'd like to create a `UIWebView` which behaves exactly like Apple's Safari when it comes to scrolling.

1. I want to have a `UINavigationBar` that appears gradually as as you scroll downwards on top of the page and hides gradually as you scroll upwards.
2. The most important thing is that I want it to always bounce just like the way Safari's `UIWebView` bounces.

In order to understand what I'm saying create a new project, add a `UIWebView` and load dribbble.com. You will notice that when you scroll down the dribbble's navigation bar stays in the same position.

But, what I want it to behave is just like Safari, here's what I want it to scroll like:
http://postimg.org/image/6e5qg6omh/

The reason is because behind the `UIWebView` (where the gray are is in the picture) I want to display an image. That image will be shown when you scroll down.

I tried setting `webView.scrollView.alwaysBouncesVertical = YES;` but it didn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, making the region of the bar hidden past the top, then set it to always slide back if a certain length (lengthOfBarVisible < lengthOfBar) {move -.5 on the x axis}

Im a rookie so I'm probably way off.

Good luck though!

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that in fact the UIWebView works exactly the way I want it to but the new WKWebView which I'm using is behaving in an odd way. There's nothing I can do I just hope that Apple fixes it.